# How to hide a variable from the program itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm not sure how to title this. Heck, this isn't even a python issue because the code is working properly. Let me explain, this might take a while.

So, I've been working in a discord bot that runs code. Probably one the worst ideas I had, but I love the potential that it could have (and the wacky outcomes of people trying to break it), [and this is what I ended up with.](https://github.com/Kurolox/HorusBot/blob/master/horus.py)

I know that it's not pretty, but it's mine and I'm quite proud of it. [It works and everything!](https://i.imgur.com/bGGkEGt.png) And while I'd love to get people to tell me how the code could be improved and how much does my code sucks, that's not exactly the problem I have.

So, this bot lets everyone run any code they want. ANYTHING. And I don't even worry about it. I'm going to be running it in a raspberry Pi that I zeroed several times, then installed docker on it. I don't really care about what could people do to it since there won't be any sensitive data. Well, almost. Here's the problem.

So, the last line in my code is this.

```
bot_client.run(token)
```

That token is the API bot key from discord. I don't really want anyone to be able to know it, since they could get their own bots in a server using it. But anyone could write a piece of code that reads the file. I'm quite lost. I'm not sure how could I protect that API key. I've tried a few things, most of them related to unix permissions and users/groups, but none of them worked because the files that the bot create will inherit the same user, so I can't put them in different users and call it a day.

Any idea about how could I do this? Just to be clear, [this is what I want to avoid.](https://i.imgur.com/tkIQ3gt.png)

Comment: Uhh, what? I think the issue here is that you're letting anyone "run any code they want. ANYTHING"

Comment: I suggest you trim this question down to 5 lines or so. Right now there's so much irrelevant noise in it that it's difficult to parse out what you want exactly. Just get to the point. Then more people will be willing and able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a general application design issue. Currently you have a main script that creates new python processes to execute the code, and by default the subprocess has full access to your disk thus to your sources.

IMHO, you should manage *at the OS level* a way so that the Python interpreter started in the subprocess has no access to the folders of the application source. But that will only come at a cost, because you will have to setup 2 different security roles and a communication channel between them.

The first idea that come to mind would be an auxilliary daemon process running under a different user having no access at all on the source folder of the application. That daemon would have to start the child Python scripts. You could use a (unix domain) socket or any other IPC channel to pass the text in one side and the input/error in other side.

I'm sorry that it is just a hint, but I now realize that you question leads to a rather broad problem.